# API Gateway change endpoint URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I was testing api gateway with dummy url and it works fine. However, I would like to change the url to other domain. Is that possible to change URL endpoint in method?

Note: I'm using HTTP Proxy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if that's what you're trying to achieve, but you can use [custom domain names](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html) in order to customize the publicly visible endpoint for your API.

If you want to change the URL of the integration endpoint, you need to open the "Integration Request" tab on the method settings, make sure the integration type is set to "HTTP Proxy" and update the "Endpoint URL" field.

Comment: I was looking for modification in method request but it was in integration request tab... Thanks!